# Automapper - Passing an upper level property as a parameter to lower level map

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to be able to access to ShipmentIdentifier property in the commented mapping part, so I can run the below assert statement successfuly. Below is the simplified version of my mapper. How can I pass the ShipmentIdentifier property while I'm mapping the WeightUnit?

```
using AutoMapper;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xunit;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IMapper mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(typeof(PrintLabelCommandMappingProfile));
        }).CreateMapper();

        CarrierLabelPrintedMessage message = new CarrierLabelPrintedMessage
        {
            ShipmentIdentifier = "AB1234",
            Cartons = new List<Carton>
            {
                new Carton
                {
                    TrackingNumber = "TestTrackingNumber",
                    LabelData =
                        new LabelData
                        {
                            Weight = 5,
                            WeightUnit = "none"
                        }
                }
            }
        };

        var command = mapper.Map<PrintLabelCommand>(message);
        Assert.Equal(command.ShipmentUnits[0].Weight.Unit, WeightUnit.None);
    }

    public class PrintLabelCommandMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public PrintLabelCommandMappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<CarrierLabelPrintedMessage, PrintLabelCommand>()
                .ForMember(cmd => cmd.ShipmentId, exp => exp.MapFrom(msg => msg.ShipmentIdentifier))
                .ForMember(cmd => cmd.ShipmentUnits, exp => exp.MapFrom(msg => msg.Cartons));

            CreateMap<Carton, ShipmentUnit>()
                .ForMember(su => su.Id, exp => exp.MapFrom(c => c.TrackingNumber))
                .ForPath(su => su.Weight.Amount, exp => exp.MapFrom(c => c.LabelData.Weight))
                .ForPath(su => su.Weight.Unit, exp => exp.MapFrom(c => c.LabelData.WeightUnit));

            CreateMap<string, WeightUnit>().ConvertUsing((str, _) =>
            {
                // I want to have ShipmentIdentifier field to be accessible in the upper level to implement the mapping logic here as below
                //if (ShipmentIdentifier.StartsWith("AB")) // it's "AB1234" in the sample
                //  return WeightUnit.None;
                //else
                    return WeightUnit.Grams;
            });
        }
    }

    public class CarrierLabelPrintedMessage
    {
        public string ShipmentIdentifier { get; set; }
        public List<Carton> Cartons { get; set; }
    }

    public class PrintLabelCommand
    {
        public string ShipmentId { get; set; }
        public List<ShipmentUnit> ShipmentUnits { get; set; }
    }

    public class Carton
    {
        public string TrackingNumber { get; set; }
        public LabelData LabelData { get; set; }
    }

    public class LabelData
    {
        public double Weight { get; set; }
        public string WeightUnit { get; set; }
    }

    public class ShipmentUnit
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public Weight Weight { get; set; }
    }

    public class Weight
    {
        public double Amount { get; set; }
        public WeightUnit Unit { get; set; }
    }

    public enum WeightUnit
    { 
        None,
        Grams,
        Kilograms
    }
}
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @Progman I added the whole class details and it can be compiled, is that what you requested?

Comment: @anilca Please provide some kind of entry point like the `Main()` method or a unit test which shows the input value you have and the result you want from the mapping. Also show how you call the `Map()` method from AutoMapper.

Comment: @Progman done, thanks

Comment: Just for fun I'd try writing the same code without Automapper. Compare them side by side. My guess is that a) the version without Automapper will be easier to read, and b) when a scenario like this comes along you'll write the code easily instead of asking "How do I do this with Automapper?"

Comment: @Scott Hannen I totally agree with you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`AfterMap()`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html?highlight=aftermap) on the `CreateMap<CarrierLabelPrintedMessage, PrintLabelCommand>()` mapping to "fix" the mapping based on the information available in `CarrierLabelPrintedMessage`. The mapping might look like this:

```
CreateMap<CarrierLabelPrintedMessage, PrintLabelCommand>()
    .ForMember(cmd => cmd.ShipmentId, exp => exp.MapFrom(msg => msg.ShipmentIdentifier))
    .ForMember(cmd => cmd.ShipmentUnits, exp => exp.MapFrom(msg => msg.Cartons))
    .AfterMap((src, target) => {
        WeightUnit targetValue = WeightUnit.Grams;
        if (src.ShipmentIdentifier.StartsWith("AB"))
        {
            targetValue = WeightUnit.None;
        }
        foreach (ShipmentUnit shipmentUnit in target.ShipmentUnits)
        {
            shipmentUnit.Weight.Unit = targetValue;
        }
    });
```